# dev_appserver.py throws unrecognized arguments: --datastore_emulator_cmd

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm running Google Cloud SDK [212.0.0] on Linux. Things have worked fine until today. Now, when I run dev_server:

$ `dev_appserver.py .`

I get this error:

```
dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments:
--datastore_emulator_cmd=/usr/platform/cloud-datastore-emulator/cloud_datastore_emulator
```

I hadn't done any updates for quite awhile, but since getting the error I did try updating the SDK with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get update google-cloud-sdk`

Have also tried other app engine directories and get the same error.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You may try not running the command with --datastore_emulator_cmd. Rather, you could from the start run dev_appserver.py in the  /bin/dev_appserver.py directory, while not using the --datastore_emulator_cmd parameter any more.

Comment: George, I'm not using any parameters--just running dev_appserver.py . in the directory of my project. But I think you're right. Somewhere a config file is appending **--datastore_emulator_cmd**, which needs removed. I've used grep to search for that string, but haven't found it.

Comment: Irrespective of having found meanwhile the configuration file, have you attempted running the command without --datastore_emulator_cmd?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem on gcloud sdk with following configuration:

```
gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 227.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.80
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.74
bq 2.0.39
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.0.2
cloud_sql_proxy 
core 2018.11.30
gsutil 4.34
```

As I've checked there is "_correct_datastore_emulator_cmd" method implemented in "DevelopmentServer" class of file "google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.p" which modifies cmd with that emulator flag.
It can be potentially reported to sdk developers.